# selenium chrome connection refused during test run

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Sometimes, but not always, when running our end-to-end tests we get a ConnectRefused exception. This only happens with chrome but not with firefox.
For us this happens *during* the test, i.e, after the test has run correctly for a while.

We are using the docker image `selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-vanadium`. (We downgraded from `-zinc` because of another issue.)
The docker image is run as part of a docker-compose which also contains our application/database.

The test itself is executed outside of docker-compose using JUnit5 and Selenium java `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.141.59:compile`.

Everything together is run on a GitLab runner using the docker executor. This means that there is another docker layer around everything, but that might not be relevant.

The actual exception is

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'runner-_f3Cf_kC-project-44-concurrent-0', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.0-8-amd64', java.version: '11.0.5'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.5sVOki}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:37949}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 4591df261c617729ec95f592ed6...}
Session ID: 4591df261c617729ec95f592ed69756b
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getLocation(RemoteWebElement.java:337)
    [...]
```

There is no further cause, the `java.net.ConnectException` is decoded from the response received by the RemoteWebDriver from the selenium-standalone process in the container. I assume this means that selenium-standalone was not able to reach chrome or the chrome-driver.

The container logs unfortunately do not contain anything useful, in particular there is no ConnectException. Increasing the log level to debug for selenium and/or chromedriver did not yield any more information.

Ideally I am looking for a solution to fix this problem, but any steps towards that are appreciated.

Comment: We also had quite a few of those (we have 250+ selenium tests in our build, so random failures were not so random). I've noticed that by removing element.clear()  the error rate has decreased a lot. Now, instead of clear we usually do:  element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME, Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.END), someText)

Comment: I would be really interested if you find out something else about this problem